# Heroku reset JSON file edited by admin panel

Tags: json, node.js, heroku

I have a **node.js** app deployed correctly on Heroku. It's a simple app that stores some values in a JSON file and it read or update that file (like it is a database).

Everything works fine (creation of new nodes in JSON, deletion, editing etc...) but it seems that every ***X*** hours the JSON file is resetted as it is in the last commit pushed to Heroku.

Is there a way to handle this without using a database? (like MongoDb for example)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with a minimal Heroku deployment, the design needs to account for a layer capable of storing state ( ie u mention Mongo ).

Your design should include a separate node from the Heroku ( app layer ) where the state resides and where your app has authorization to do HTTP actions (POST, GET) on the state stored in your JSON.

The reason for your intermittent resets/reverts of the JSON is involved with  Heroku's service tier and with the fact that your apps state is cycling UP and DOWN .

Look for a sample Heroku app with minimal persistent layer....